# how to update server DataBase from android using java

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to insert data in MySQL using java class file.
I know how to update by calling the .php file using HTTP.
But want I want to know is  it possible to to same using java class file on server side .
 Lets say I have a java application on server side which is using MySQL database to show a records .
 Know I want to update database from android without calling php file but to call java class file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating the server database you should use `Servlet` in `Java` and for updating the `db` call the `Servlet`